# setState doesn't set values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fetch

We got a ReactJS frontend delivered for our school project. We have to make a Laravel backend for it. I'm using an API to fetch the dashboard layout from the database. The current frontend makes use of this variable:

```
const originalLayouts = getFromLS("layouts") || [];
```

To set the state from the local storage with this function:

```
function getFromLS(key) {
    let ls = {};
    if (global.localStorage) {
        try {
            ls = JSON.parse(global.localStorage.getItem("rgl-8")) || {};
        } catch (e) {
            /*Ignore*/
        }
    }
    return ls[key];
}
```

Where the states are set:

```
this.state = {
            items: originalLayouts.map(function(i, key, list) {
                return {
                    i: originalLayouts[key].i,
                    x: originalLayouts[key].x,
                    y: originalLayouts[key].y,
                    w: originalLayouts[key].w,
                    h: originalLayouts[key].h,
                    widget: originalLayouts[key].widget,
                    minW: originalLayouts[key].minW,
                    minH: originalLayouts[key].minH,
                    maxH: originalLayouts[key].maxH
                };
            }),
            selectedOption: '',
            newCounter: originalLayouts.length
        };
```

To fetch the data from the database and put the data into the items state I made this function:

```
loadData = () => {

        let dashboardId = 1;

        return axios
            .get('api/dashboards/' + dashboardId)
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    this.setState({
                        originalLayouts: result.data,
                        selectedOption: '',
                        newCounter: originalLayouts.length
                    });
                    console.log(result.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('error: ', error);
                })
    };
```

And I call this function in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
}
```

When I console log result it shows me this:

```
 data: Array(2), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data: (2) [{…}, {…}]
headers: {date: "Tue, 23 Oct 2018 08:18:41 +0000, Tue, 23 Oct 2018 08:18:41 GMT", host: "127.0.0.1:8000", x-powered-by: "PHP/7.2.3", x-ratelimit-remaining: "58", content-type: "application/json", …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

And when I console log result.data I get:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, dashboardId: 1, w: 2, h: 5, x: 0, …}
1: {id: 2, dashboardId: 1, w: 2, h: 1, x: 0, …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Why is originalLayouts not set with the data from the arrays? Is this because I also have a `dashboardId` and `id` in my arrays? I also thought it could be something with setting the states because it makes use of the originalLayouts veriable. Or am I still missing something in my function? I'm not very experienced with React so any help is useful.

**Update:**

I changed:

```
this.setState({
    originalLayouts: result.data,
    selectedOption: '',
    newCounter: originalLayouts.length
});
```

to:

```
this.setState({
    items: result.data,
    selectedOption: '',
    newCounter: originalLayouts.length
});
```

This gives me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: ReactGridLayout: ReactGridLayout.children[0].static must be a boolean!
```

So that probably means I'm not setting the properties properly now.

**Update 2:**

In my database the properties `moved` and `static` were saved as `0` instead of `false`. So I changed those properties to `false` but I still got the same error:

```
ReactGridLayout: ReactGridLayout.children[0].static must be a boolean!
```

Comment: Your `originalLayouts` are actually `items` in your state, try changing it when setting in response callback

Comment: I'm getting an error now so I think I'm getting closer.. it says ReactGridLayout.children[0].static must be a boolean. So that probably has something to do with the data i'm trying to set to the states.

Comment: No, this is probably the error from this third party component `ReactGridLayout` some property is not set right.

Comment: Don't you think this have something to do with my array? Because in my this.state it starts with i, x, y etc. and my array starts with id, dashboardId, w etc.

Comment: As log as you have all properties in your array, order nor extra properties doesn't matter.

Comment: So it only takes the values I have in my array regardless of the order the values?

Comment: Exactly, the issue will occur if you use some property that is not part of the object.

Comment: Seems the fetch returns false as a string instead as a boolean so when I fix this the error should been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In your loadData(), you are setting the state of "originalLayouts" but your key in your initial state is "items". Have you tried to do this ?

```
this.setState({
                items: result.data, // Here put items instead of originalLayouts
                selectedOption: '',
                newCounter: originalLayouts.length
              });
```

Then you can call `this.state.items` to get your result.data

Comment: I'm getting an error now so I think I'm getting closer.. it says ReactGridLayout.children[0].static must be a boolean. So that probably has something to do with the data i'm trying to set to the states.

Comment: You can log this.state.items to see what is inside. Then I guess the error comes from what you do with the data afterward